# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PackageA"

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and iOS. I get the following error, when I run `pod install`

I tried every solution here [could not find compatible versions for pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638059/could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod) but none works. I always get the same error

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PackageA":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    PackageA (= 2.3.0, ~> 2.3.0)

  In Podfile:
    PackageB (= 3.12.0) was resolved to 3.12.0, which depends on
      PackageA (~> 2.3.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `PackageA (= 2.3.0, ~> 2.3.0), PackageA (~> 2.3.0)`.
```

What does `~>` mean?

What is a `spec` and where to edit it?

What does `(= 2.3.0, ~> 2.3.0)`

How does the snapshot and podfile work together ?

What else can I try to fix my issue ? Any workaround ?

(I cannot post my entire file here because the packages are private and belong to a paid provider)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Payhere required a higher deployment target. Uncomment the platform line in podfile (its located in the ios folder)
and change like this

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

then try again. it's should work.

Answer (score -1):

Delete *Podfile.lock* and then try

```
 pod repo update
```

This will most probably fix your issue.

If this doesn't work you can do

```
 pod deintegrate
 pod install
 pod update
```

For other queries you can read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213751/what-is-the-usage-of-in-cocoapods) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655457/what-is-the-significance-of-podspec-in-cocoapod)

Comment: This is part of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638059/could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod which I mentioned in my question saying that I already tried everything. Can you suggest something else please ?

Comment: @TSR try reisntalling pod
-> pod repo remove master

-> pod setup

-> pod install